# Why does string variable store only first symbol?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone tell me why the LikeString variable is always `%` ? Here's the code:

```
DECLARE @LikeString NVARCHAR = CAST('%4075%' AS nvarchar)
SELECT @LikeString
```

I've tried this in SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2012, but `@LikeString` always contains `%` instead of `%4075%` as I expected.

Comment: You're gonna down vote me because because I'm having trouble with data types. I've seen worse questions on this forum...

Comment: I don't understand the down votes.

Comment: Thanks Tilo... appreciate the support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for `char`, `varchar`, `nchar`, `nvarchar`

> When size is not specified in variable declaration statement, the default length is 1

```
DECLARE @LikeString NVARCHAR(6) = CAST('%4075%' AS nvarchar(6))
SELECT @LikeString
```

or simpler:

```
DECLARE @LikeString NVARCHAR(6) = N'%4075%'
SELECT @LikeString
```

Comment: Thanks ASh that works, but I'm a little confused why specifying a length forces SQL to respect the numbers when they are already in a string literal.

Comment: @gummo, when you didn't specify length, {4075%} was cut. it doesn't matter - digits or letters or other characters.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I'll try not to forget that between now and the next time I need to do this.

Comment: @gummo, please, check update. i don't understand why we need `CAST`

Comment: Thanks ASh. Indeed it is unnecessary. Originally I put the CAST in because I knew this had something to do with the data type, but wasn't sure what...

Answer (score 1):

From the SQL Server 2008 R2 Transact-SQL documentation...

"When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified with the CAST function, the default length is 30."

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939(v=sql.105).aspx

You are using a variable declaration statement, therefore all but the first character is being truncated from the string when you attempt to initialize the variable with "%4075%".

Therefore, as others have stated, the solution is to specify the length of your nvarchar data type variable.

Comment: Thanks for the further clarification... that is helpful. So CAST defaults to 30 but then it must have been cut off by the declaration.

Comment: Exactly!  So this works as well: DECLARE @LikeString NVARCHAR(10) = CAST('%4075%' AS nvarchar)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
DECLARE @LikeString NVARCHAR(50) = CAST('%4075%' AS nvarchar(50))
SELECT @LikeString
```